# Tesseract Failed to open .tr file issue

Tags: ocr, tesseract, training-data

I'm new to Tesseract OCR and and I'm following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-ocr-with-tesseract-a4341e4564b6) tutorial to create new train data for a new language and stuck with the following errors. I have tried and searched for days to overcome this issue and could not find any.

I'm using Windows, Tesseract v5.0.0 (Latest version) & jTessBoxEditor

This is my command prompt:

```
F:\My R&D Softwares\tutorial>tesseract newfn.fn1.exp0.tif newfn.fn1.exp0 nobatch box.train
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v5.0.0-alpha.20210506 with Leptonica
Page 1
APPLY_BOXES:
   Boxes read from boxfile:       4
   Found 4 good blobs.
Generated training data for 1 words
Page 2
APPLY_BOXES:
   Boxes read from boxfile:       4
   Found 4 good blobs.
Generated training data for 1 words
Page 3
APPLY_BOXES:
   Boxes read from boxfile:       4
   Found 4 good blobs.
Generated training data for 1 words

F:\My R&D Softwares\tutorial>unicharset_extractor newfn.fn1.exp0.box
Extracting unicharset from box file newfn.fn1.exp0.box
Wrote unicharset file unicharset

F:\My R&D Softwares\tutorial>shapeclustering -F font_properties.txt -U unicharset -O newfn.unicharset newfn.fn1.exp0.tr
Reading shapeclustering ...
Failed to open tr file: shapeclustering
Reading newfn.fn1.exp0.tr ...

F:\My R&D Softwares\tutorial>mftraining -F font_properties.txt -U unicharset -O newfn.unicharset newfn.fn1.exp0.tr echo Clustering..
Warning: No shape table file present: shapetable
Reading mftraining ...
Failed to open tr file: mftraining
Reading newfn.fn1.exp0.tr ...
Reading echo ...
Failed to open tr file: echo
Reading Clustering.. ...
Failed to open tr file: Clustering..
Flat shape table summary: Number of shapes = 9 max unichars = 1 number with multiple unichars = 0

F:\My R&D Softwares\tutorial>cntraining newfn.fn1.exp0.tr
Reading newfn.fn1.exp0.tr ...
Clustering ...

F:\My R&D Softwares\tutorial>
```

with this I can not create normproto, intemp, and pffmtable files at all.
what is this

> Failed to open tr file:

error and how can I solve this? (please note that the .tr file is in the same location which stated in cmd )

Following is the first lines of the created tr file:
[newfn.fn1.exp0.tr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffwzy.jpg)

Comment: I did uninstall Tesseract 5 & install Tesseract 4. Then it worked!